# Using a function parameter in place of a string constant in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use the following function to create a foreign server using FDW through a function. However, when I replace the string constant of **host** with the function parameter ***$1***, I get a syntax error. Am I missing anything here?

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foreign_server_create(host_name text) RETURNS VOID
AS $$
    CREATE SERVER postgres_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host $1, dbname 'xx', port 'xxxx');
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: You need to build a dynamic statement and EXECUTE it.

Comment: thanks, I'll provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foreign_server_create(host_name text) RETURNS VOID
AS $$
 EXECUTE format ('CREATE SERVER postgres_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host %L, dbname 'xx', port 'xxxx')', $1);
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```